# how to filter the table so that it can give me only required values?

Tags: sql

I want to filter data in sql
For example if i have 4 column 
Project, technology, starttime and endtime

I want to filter my report when project and technology values are same in multiple rows then only select minimum value in starttime and maximum value in endtime

Can anyone tell me the query in sql to filter the table in this way
My query is

```
Select * from db.pro
Where Min(starttime) & Max(endtime)
Group by project, technology;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a basic `GROUP BY`:

```
select project, technology, Min(starttime), Max(endtime)
from db.pro
Group by project, technology;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. Please have look here to have more idea about [`how GROUP BY works`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

```
Select project, technology, Min(starttime), Max(endtime)
from db.pro 
Group by project, technology;
```